How can I add multiple files wither aider coder AI (As it is set to default limit of 3)
from aider.coder import Coder

fnames=["file2.py","file2.py","file3.py","file4.py"]
coder = Coder.create(main_model=model, fnames=fnames)

coder.run("some prompt")

So in this when fnames length is greater than 3, following error is being thrown:
File "path\my_venv\Lib\site-packages\aider\coders\base_coder.py", line 

1035, in get_rel_fname

    return os.path.relpath(fname, self.root)

                                  ^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'EditBlockCoder' object has no attribute 'root'


If the length of fnames is less than or equal to 3 it works fine.
Is there any way to add more than 3 files to fnames?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

did you check if you have all files file2.py,file2.py,file3.py, file4.py in folder? maybe it can't find one of the files? Or maybe you have to use /full/path/to/file.py
